# How do I escape exclamation mark within CSS selector using Less?

Tags: css, less

Suppose we have the following:

```
.foo:!bar { color: red; }
```

How can we escape the exclamation mark so that Less doesn't fail to compile it?

Comment: what is `!bar`? that looks like it would be a syntax error

Comment: @Martin It's for a widget in Qt (C++). In this case it applies if `.foo` doesn't have any children. That's how they implemented it in their version of CSS unfortunately, so I ran into this issue.